# Eloquent select pivot and update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am developing an app that allows a user to publish a Message and send it to multiple Devices.

`Message` and `Devices` are both models which are linked with a `device_message` pivot table using `message_id` and `device_id` as the same message can be sent to many devices.

I have an Event that fires when the `Message` is created. The event sends a push notification to the devices I would like to create a new column in the `device_message` pivot table to record whether that message was sent successfully to the device. This column is called `success` and is a boolean.

The event has a foreach loop which selects the relevant message record in the `device_message` table. Within this loop the push notification is sent. If the notification is sent successfully I want to change the `success` column in the pivot table to `true`. How do I do this?

To give some context this statement returns all the records in the pivot table for the relevant devices.

```
$event->message->belongsToMany('Aiir\Models\Device')->withPivot('device_id', 'message_id')->where('device_id', $event->device->id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `updateExistingPivot` on the *belongsToMany* relation, like this:

```
$message = Message::findOrFail($id);
$message->devices()->updateExistingPivot($deviceID, ['success' => true]);
```

This will set *success* to true on your pivot table.